# NameError - uninitialized constant AjaxDatatablesRails::Datatable::Column::Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, postgresql, datatables

I'm trying to set up server-side DataTables using the `ajax-datatables-rails` gem. I've more or less followed the guide, with just a couple minor changes. I can't figure out why I'm running into this error. When navigating to the index page, I receive a 500 error through the AJAX request:

`NameError - uninitialized constant AjaxDatatablesRails::Datatable::Column::Search`

Any help would be appreciated!

```
Ruby 2.5.1
Rails 5.2.4.3
PostgreSQL 10.3
ajax-datatables-rails 1.2.0
```

#### config/initializers/ajax_datatables_rails.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

AjaxDatatablesRails.configure do |config|
  config.db_adapter = :pg
end
```

#### app/assets/javascripts/datatables.js

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
  $('#users-datatable').dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
      "url": $('#users-datatable').data('source')
    },
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "columns": [
      {"data": "first_name"},
      {"data": "last_name"},
      {"data": "email"}
    ]
  });
});
```

#### app/datatables/user_datatable.rb

```
class UserDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::ActiveRecord
  def initialize(params, opts = {})
    @view = opts[:view_context]
    super
  end

  def view_columns
    @view_columns ||= {
      first_name: { source: "User.first_name" },
      last_name: { source: "User.last_name" },
      email: { source: "User.email" }
    }
  end

  def data
    records.map do |record|
      {
        first_name: record.first_name,
        last_name: record.last_name,
        email: record.email
      }
    end
  end

  def get_raw_records
    User.all
  end
end
```

#### config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users, only: :index do
    get "search", to: "users#search", on: :collection
  end
end
```

#### app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  # GET /users
  def index; end

  # GET /users/search
  def search
    render json: UserDatatable.new(params)
  end
end
```

#### app/views/users/index.html.erb

```
<table id="users-datatable" class="table" data-source="<%= search_users_path(format: :json) %>">
  <thead class="table-header">
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="search-boxes">
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody class="table-body"></tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a fix. I needed to downgrade from the latest version of the gem, `1.2.0`, to `1.1.0`.

#### Gemfile

`gem 'ajax-datatables-rails', '1.1.0'`